# rawQuery Android development

Tags: android, sqlite

I created my database and I am trying to get from my table the count of all fields in which the boolean value is true, count them and group them by key. When I run this query in mysql, it works. Also if I run the query as                                             `String query = "SELECT "+LATITUDE+", "+LONGITUDE+", COUNT(*) FROM "+CHECKED_IN_TABLE+" GROUP BY "+LATITUDE+", "+LONGITUDE;` It would also work but this would give me a count grouped by lat and Lon. Any ideas? The error is traced back to Cursor declaration, line 4, I think due to rawQuery!. Thanks in advance.

```
public List<String> getCurrentCrowd(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+LATITUDE+", "+LONGITUDE+",COUNT(*) FROM "+CHECKED_IN_TABLE+" WHERE currnet = true GROUP BY "+LATITUDE+", "+LONGITUDE;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    List<String> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            String latitude = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LATITUDE));
            String longitude = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LONGITUDE));
            int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COUNT(*)"));
            locations.add(latitude+","+longitude+","+count);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return locations;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is that there is no boolean type in **SQLite** (which **IS NOT MySQL**) and therefore your cannot use **`= true`**. Instead you would have to indicate and test for true or false another way.

> 2.1. Boolean Datatype SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1
>   (true).

[Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

The most efficient way would be to assign a value to currnet that is either 1 (true) or 0 (false) and then use `WHERE currnet <> 0` to reflect true.

If you consider the following, where current is set to either 1 or 0 :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS checked_in;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS checked_in (longitude REAL, latitude REAL, currnet INTEGER);
INSERT INTO checked_in VALUES
    (100.10,200.10,1),(100.10,200.10,0),(100.10,200.10,1),
    (120.10,200.10,1),(120.10,200.10,0),(120.10,200.10,1),
    (120.10,210.10,1),(120.10,210.10,1),(120.10,210.10,1),
    (130.10,200.10,0),(130.10,200.10,0),(130.10,200.10,0),
    (140.10,200.10,1),(140.10,200.10,0),(140.10,200.10,0)
;
SELECT * FROM checked_in;
```

The table in full would be :-

[image]

If you then consider you query which would resolve to :-

```
SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE,COUNT(*) FROM CHECKED_IN WHERE currnet = true GROUP BY LATITUDE, LONGITUDE;
```

This fails because **true** is not an SQLite keyword and is then taken to be a column name e.g. :-

```
 > no such column: true
```

However, if you instead use :-

```
SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE,COUNT(*) FROM checked_in WHERE currnet <> 0 GROUP BY LATITUDE, LONGITUDE;
```

The result is :-

[image]

Therefore you need to use SQLite according to it's SQL rather than according to MySQL SQL. If you used a column type of BOOL or BOOLEAN that in itself is not an issue due to SQLite's flexibility. However you cannot use TRUE or FALSE for comparison. Otherwise your code appears to be fine.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your conceptual explanation.